# How do i link a series of SVG animations with CSS animations simulatenously

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a cursor move up, click with a pulse, followed by an expanding and fading circle.

I have managed to make everything work perfectly by just using svg animation but i used CSS code to animate the pulse.

Is is possible to link the CSS code with an ID or something so the whole sequence is in a loop? Or will i just have to time it perfectly?

```
    @keyframes pulse_animation {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    28% {transform: scale(1);}
    29% {transform: scale(0.9)}
    30% { transform: scale(0.8); }
    31% {transform: scale(0.9)}
    32% {transform: scale(1);}
    80% { transform: scale(1); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
     }
    #pulse {
    animation-name: pulse_animation;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    transform-origin:77% 33%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0;
    }

    <g id="cursor">

    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
              id="arrow"
              attributeType="XML"
              type="translate"
              dur="1.5s"
              values="100,200;0,0"
              begin="0s; last.end"
              fill="remove" />

    <animate attributeName="opacity"
         values="1;0" dur="1s"
                 begin="last.end"
         fill="freeze"
         repeatCount=""/>

    <animate attributeName="opacity"
         values="0;1" dur="0.5s"
                 begin="last.end"
         fill="freeze"
         repeatCount=""/>

     <circle id="cursor-circle" class="st20" cx="0" cy="0" r="6.9" transform="translate(525.6 185.5)"  >

       <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      id="grow"
         type="scale"
         values="0 0;7 7"
         additive="sum" 

         begin="arrow.end+0.2s"
         dur="1s"
         repeatCount="" />

    <animate attributeName="opacity"
             id="last"
         values="1;0" dur="1s"
                 begin="arrow.end+0.2s"
         repeatCount=""/>
    </circle>
    <polygon id="pulse" class="st19" points="512.6,163.4 517.8,210.9 527.1,198.4 536.9,215.4 545.4,210.4 535.6,193.5 551,191.7"   > 


    </polygon>
    </g>
```

Comment: Timing it perfectly as CSS is dumb as nails when it comes to animation sequences :) (aka, it is not aware of sequences). However I would actually advice to put _all_ animations in the CSS so you can tweak things more specifically. But thats just me.

Comment: I've put all animations in the CSS and it's worked! Thanks for your help